# hot swapped warning without making any changes (Spring tool suite 3.9)

Tags: spring-tool-suite

When running my code in debug mode, I keep getting 2 error messages:

```
Could not delete [path_to]\productiondb.log. May be locked by another process
```

I don't know what process might be locking it. It comes when I make changes to the code while my Pivotal tc Server is running in debug mode, but it dosent seem to create a lot's of trouble. Sometimes however, I get this warning:

[image: Hote Code Replace Failed]

Also due to some changes. I usally just restart the server and move on. This isen't the real problem, the real problem is that I get these messages when I havent doen any changes. Somethimes it accures when I run a certen part of the code, other times i occurs when I open certen codes in sts, however, it doen't seem to stop at the same place twice.

I am suspecting that this has something to do with git. I am using git to change between versions and doing tests. So I am thinking that STS has some of the code in memory from before I changed branche with git, and isen't updating it before I run or open the file with that code. But I am rather new to both sts and git, and can't be certan that it would work that way. If it is, does anyone know how to update sts after I have changed branch? If it is not, does anyone know what might causing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you run an app in debug mode, the Eclipse Debugger tells the application when code gets changed and tries to use the debug API to swap in the new code into the running application. This is especially useful if you debug your code, hit a breakpoint, step through the code, fit the issue, change the code, and press save. At that moment, the Eclipse compiler updates the class file and tells the running JVM to swap in the new code. If that succeeds, the debugger will jump back to the last stack frame and the execution of your app will continue with the beginning of the method that you entered. This allows you to directly continue to debug and step through the updated code without restarting the app.

While this is a great feature of the JVM, it is very limited in terms of what scope of changes to the classes the JVM can deal with while doing this hot-swap. It is usually limited to method implementations. So adding new methods, adding or deleting members of the class, etc, are not supported. As a result, the above screenshot will appear. It means that the JVM wasn't able to hot-swap the changed code and will continue to run with the previously loaded code instead of the changed one.

Comment: Thanks for the update, It is good to undertand how it works better. But I get these messages when I haven't done any changes. As stated in my post, I might have changed git branch, and therby changing a large portion of the code, but I reset the server whenever i would change branche.

Comment: When you switch to a different branch, it will trigger a re-compile in your workspace and therefore updated class files, which will trigger the debugger to try hot-swapping the code. You can change this default behavior in the preferences and prevent the IDE from trying hot-swapping to the code or displaying errors, if you prefer a different behavior (`Preferences -> Java -> Debug`). Hope that helps.